# Apache Spark: In SparkSql, are sql's vulnerable to Sql Injection

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

Scenario:

Say there is a table in **Hive**, and it is queried using the below **SparkSql in Apache Spark**, where table name is passed as an argument and concatenated to the query.

In case of non-distributed system, I have basic understanding of SQL-Injection vulnerability and in the context of JDBC understand the usage of createStatement/preparedStatement in the those kind of scenario.

But what about this scenario in the case of sparksql, is this code vulnerable? Any insights ?

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val sconf = new SparkConf().setAppName("TestApp")
    val sparkContext = new SparkContext(sconf)
    val hiveSqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sparkContext)

    val tableName = args(0)    // passed as an argument

    val tableData  =  hiveSqlContext.sql("select IdNUm, Name from hiveSchemaName." + tableName + " where IdNum <> '' ")
                                        .map( x => (x.getString(0), x.getString(1)) ).collectAsMap()


    ................
    ...............

}
```

Comment: `def safeSql(query,**args): spark.udf.register("arg", lambda x: args[x]) return(spark.sql(query)) safeSql("select arg('a'),arg('b')",a=4,b="O'Malley").show()
`
The above is in pyspark but it can be done in Scala or other languages. The trick is to register an udf.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following in Spark 2.0:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
val conf = new SparkConf()

val sparkSession = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("TestApp")
  .config(conf)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()

val tableName = args(0)    // passed as an argument

val tableData  =  sparkSession
.table(tableName)
.select($"IdNum", $"Name")
.filter($"IdNum" =!= "")
.map( x => (x.getString(0), x.getString(1)) ).collectAsMap()


................
...............
```

}`

Comment: SparkSession is available in v2.0 and above. The restriction is need to get it done in 1.5. Is it possible to do similar thing in using SparkContext via sqlContext or hiveSqlContext?

Comment: you can use SqlContext instead of SparkSession

Answer (score 1):

In Java usually the most common way to handle sql injection threats is to use prepared statements.

you can use the Java libraries or google prepared statements in Scala to look for Scala libraries for that. 
Since Scala is used also in web applications I'm sure such libraries exists..

Comment: Yes, for regular applications we do go the way you said, but was looking in context of Apache Spark Sql.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a built in solution in spark... which makes sense as it isn't intended on being an application db which will get input from users.
if you want to go the "spark way" you can use the dataframe api without sql like the other answer suggested if that fits your scenerio