# scala generic method less boilerplate

Tags: scala, generics

How can I prevent some code repetition for a generic method in scala? My code only compiled when the type parameter was bound to the trait and not the method.

As you can see, I currently repeat the type parameters being passed to the trait and mehtod.

```
trait MyTrait[T <: Product, C <: OtherTrait] {

  def provide(spark: SparkSession, c: C): Dataset[T]
}

object ConcreteProvider
  extends MyTrait[MyCaseClass, MyCaseClassConfiguration] {
    override def provide(
        spark: SparkSession,
        c: MyCaseClassConfiguration): Dataset[MyCaseClass] = {
        spark.sql(s"SELECT field1, field2 FROM ${c.mydb}.${c.mytable}")
          .as[MyCaseClass]
    }
  }
```

Comment: You still need to bind `MyCaseClass`, `MyCaseClassConfiguration` and `CellFeedSubscriberConfiguration`, so I'm not sure what repetition you are concerned about. You don't show how the parameter `c` is used inside `provide()`. You should be able factor out the body of `provide` into `provideHelper` and define `provide` in the trait.

Comment: I edited the example to show usage of `c`.

Comment: What do you mean that I still need to bind? I thought thyt referencing my type parameters within `[T]` should be fine?

Comment: Indeed. Renamed

Comment: Also note that your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL injection. You should probably use higher-level SQL APIs. For Spark, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41941472/apache-spark-in-sparksql-are-sqls-vulnerable-to-sql-injection

Answer (score 0):

In general, Scala doesn't infer type arguments for methods. However, in your case, you can actually use the (quite concise) lambda syntax, since `MyTrait` in your example is a "SAM" (single abstract method) type:

```
val ConcreteProvider: MyTrait[MyCaseClass, MyCaseClassConfiguration] =
    (spark, c) => spark.sql("SELECT ...").as[MyCaseClass]
```

Now your argument types are nicely inferred.

Caveats:

- `ConcreteProvider` is now a `val` instead of an `object`. For many (most?) purposes, this will not matter.
- This cannot be defined at the top level, so you may have to put it in a `package object`.
- This will fail if you add another abstract method to `MyTrait`.

Comment: Another caveat is that there's no Spark for 2.12, and IIRC for 2.11 you need `-Xexperimental` flag too.